# Python - Issue with replacing several different segments in dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am still fairly new in Python and I have some trouble with my script.

I have sentences in a file that appear as follow:

```
Comment "This is my line with [special words <mots spéciaux>] that I will need to swap"
Translation "Voici ma phrase avec des [mots spéciaux incorrects] que je dois modifier"
```

I need to take the [mots spéciaux incorrects] from my translation line and replace it with the  part of my comment line.

I have created a dictionary with comment-translation as key-value. I go over the dictionary and use regex to capture the `[special words]` segments. 
My script works fine if I only have one word per line to change. However, whenever I have more than one segment, only the first one is changed.

```
for i in lines_dict:
    brackets_context = re.findall(r'\[[\w|\s]* <[\w|\s]*>\]', i)
    if brackets_context:
        print(i, lines_dict[i])

        target_brackets = re.search(r'\[[\w|\s]*', i).group()
        source_brackets = re.search(r'<([\w|\s]*)>', i).group()
        brackets_translation = re.search(r'\[[\w|\s]*\]', lines_dict[i]).group()

        new_translation = lines_dict[i].replace(brackets_translation, target_brackets)

        print("New translation %s\n" % new_translation)

        lines_dict[i] = new_translation
```

I imagine there is a mush simpler way to do what I need but I am completely stuck. I have tried several things and looked at other answered questions, but I don't find something that works on my script and I cannot seem to be able to go through the whole line and replace everything and I am getting slightly desperate… Would anyone have an idea on how I should proceed?

So, my current input is a file with many blocks such as this one:

```
comment "Vous avez la liste des [growers <exploitants>] liés aux [blocks <parcelles>] saisies dans l'[work order <ordre de travail>]."
translation "You have the list of [operators] related to the [plots] entered in the [work order]."
```

And I need to get this as output:

```
comment "Vous avez la liste des [growers <exploitants>] liés aux [blocks <parcelles>] saisies dans l'[work order <ordre de travail>]."
translation "You have the list of growers related to the blocks entered in the work order."
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mre], including input - i.e. `lines_dict`, desired output, and current output. The main thing is desired output, which based on what you've provided, seems like `"Voici ma phrase avec des [special words] que je dois modifier"`, but it's not totally clear. Also it seems like the dict part is irrelevant -- just focus on the strings. BTW I speak a bit of French if that's helpful.

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you ! I have just edited my question, is this clearer ?

Comment: It's better but still could use some work. Firstly, that's not a valid dict. Next, the capitalization on "contacts" doesn't match between the target and output. As well I'd recommend using a shorter, clearer example cause it's a lot to read and the translations "SMS" -> "SMS" and "contacts" -> "contacts" are ambiguous. Lastly if the `id` row is not relevant, remove it from the example.

Comment: Oh and again, the dict is not relevant. For the purpose of this question I'd recommend ignoring it and focusing on the two strings.

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you again, I changed the example with a shorter and clearer one, hope it helps. I am not sure I understood what you meant with my dictionary not being relevant? Do you mean there would be a simpler way to access all the comments with its corresponding translation than with a dictionary, or was I using it wrongly?

Comment: This is a good use of a dict, but I mean it's not relevant to the problem you're trying to solve. The problem is about manipulating two strings, so the data structure the strings are in doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's ignore the dict for now and just focus on the strings:

```
comment = "Vous avez la liste des [growers <exploitants>] liés aux [blocks <parcelles>] saisies dans l'[work order <ordre de travail>]."
translation = "You have the list of [operators] related to the [plots] entered in the [work order]."
```

Essentially what you're trying to do is replace parts of the `translation` with the corresponding parts of the `comment`. So `re.sub` would be a good tool to use on the `translation`. It can take a replacement function, which we could hook up to a function that searches `comment`.

So first let's use `re.finditer` to get the replacement strings:

```
targets = re.finditer(r'\[(.*?) <.*?>\]', comment)
```

Here I'm using `?` to do [non-greedy matches](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy), and `.*` to keep things simple (you can replace it if needed). Also note that I'm putting the important bit in group 1.

Next the replacement:

```
new_translation = re.sub(r'\[.*?\]', lambda _: next(targets).group(1), translation)
```

Let's break down the replacement function, `lambda _: next(targets).group(1)`:

- `_` - `re.sub` passes in a match object, but we don't need it, so the underscore indicates that we're ignoring the argument
- [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) - Get the next item from the iterator `targets`

Output:

```
print(new_translation)
# -> You have the list of growers related to the blocks entered in the work order.
```

Comment: It works wonders, thank you!! I just still have some trouble understanding the lambda function, and the explanations I read online do not really help me... Would it be too much to ask for some more explanation as to why you are using a lambda function here and what it does in this context?

Comment: @Basile It gets the target strings from `comment` one at a time. There's nothing more to it than that, but the way it does it is a little complicated. Is there anything in particular you're confused about with how it works?  I'm using a lambda cause the use case doesn't warrant writing a full `def`.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand better... I think I am just a little confused with lambda as I have never used it before. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Basile Welcome! Yeah lambdas are confusing, but basically they're just anonymous functions, sort of like simplified `def`s.